# Sound while the key is pressed in pyglet or pygame

Tags: python, pygame, pyglet

```
import pygame as pg
import time
import random
import pyglet
from pygame import mixer
pg.init()
mixer.init()
sx=1920
sy=1080
x=100
y=100
xP=yP=3
score=scorem=0
size=(sx,sy)
screen=pg.display.set_mode(size)
pg.display.set_caption('CybeRun')
font=pg.font.SysFont('valorax',128)
RED=(255,0,0)
GREEN=(0,255,0)
BLUE=(0,0,255)
BLACK=(0,0,0)
WHITE=(255,255,255)
FPS=60
gg=pg.image.load('hz.png')
cyru=font.render("CyberRun",1,BLACK,WHITE)
tw,th=cyru.get_size()
zad=pg.image.load('zad.jpg')
zadOK=pg.transform.scale(zad, (1920,1080))
width=1920
i=0
f=1
mixer.music.load('FON.wav')
UPm=pyglet.media.load("UP.mp3")
DOWNm=pyglet.media.load("DOWN.mp3")
mixer.music.play(-1)

while True:
    for ev in pg.event.get():
        if ev.type==pg.QUIT:
            exit()
    screen.fill(BLACK)
    screen.blit(zadOK,(i,0))
    screen.blit(zadOK,(width+i,0))
    if i==-width:
        screen.blit(zadOK,(width+i,0))
        i=0
    i-=1
    screen.blit(cyru,(((sx-tw)//2),0))
    screen.blit(gg,(x,y))
    key=pg.key.get_pressed()
    if key[pg.K_UP]:      

        y-=yP
        UPm.play()
    if key[pg.K_DOWN]: 
    
        y+=yP
        DOWNm.play()
    pg.display.update()
```

I was trying to write my first game. As planned, at the very bottom of the code, I want the desired sound to be made whenever the up or down key is pressed. But the trouble is that when you click the sound (sounds) overlap each other. I've tried everything I can, but nothing helps. I'm a beginner and I don't understand much yet(

Comment: i am not sure why this question got a downvote? given that a good attempt was made by a beginner...

Comment: as a side note, as a beginner, it would be helpful to yourself to try to read some of the docs and maybe watch a few tutorials (in particular, the code would be cleaner with `functions` and `classes`.  here is a general `pygame` video: https://youtu.be/O1ud-tWPS2c, and there are many others at different levels.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use the `KEYDOW` and `KEYUP` events for your task.
a [`Player`](https://pyglet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/modules/media.html#pyglet.media.player.Player) object and [`queue`](https://pyglet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/modules/media.html#pyglet.media.player.Player.queue) the sound.
[`play()`](https://pyglet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/modules/media.html#pyglet.media.player.Player.play) the sound on `KEYDOWN` and [`delete()`](https://pyglet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/modules/media.html#pyglet.media.player.Player.delete) the sound on `KEYUP`.
Also `delete` the sound currently playing when a key is pressed.

```py
upPlayer = pyglet.Player()
upPlayer.queue(UPm)
downPlayer = pyglet.Player()
downPlayer.queue(DOWNm)

while True:
    for ev in pg.event.get():
        if ev.type == pg.QUIT:
            exit()

        if ev.type == pg.KEYDOWN:
            if ev.key == pg.K_UP:
                downPlayer.delete()
                upPlayer.play()
            if ev.key == pg.K_DOWN:
                upPlayer.delete()
                downPlayer.play()

        if ev.type == pg.KEYUP:
            if ev.key == pg.K_UP:
                upPlayer.delete()
            if ev.key == pg.K_DOWN:
                downPlayer.delete()

    # [...]
```

The keyboard events (see [pygame.event](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html) module) occur only once when the state of a key changes. The `KEYDOWN` event occurs once every time a key is pressed. `KEYUP` occurs once every time a key is released. Use the keyboard events for a single action such as starting sound playback.

[`pygame.key.get_pressed()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/key.html#pygame.key.get_pressed) returns a sequence with the state of each key. If a key is held down, the state for the key is `1`, otherwise `0`. It is a snapshot of the keys at that very moment The new state of the keys must be retrieved continuously in each frame. Use [`pygame.key.get_pressed()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/key.html#pygame.key.get_pressed) to evaluate the current state of a button and get continuous movement.

Comment: @ТимурГалеев `delete` the sound currently playing when a key is pressed. See the answer.

Comment: I did it! Let it be through crutches, but this is for my happiness too! Thank you for your help!!